# Error uploading large files using PHP 5.6 & Apache 2.4

Tags: php, apache

I've been fighting this problem for three days now on my Windows dev workstation. I already researched a lot and changed a lot of settings in both Apache's httpd.conf and PHP's php.ini, and haven't made any visible progress. The problem is that I'm able to upload image files up to 100KB, but somewhere between 100KB and 300KB I start to get timeouts. I want to be able to upload images up to 1MB.

At some point before it times out I put a breakpoint on the PHP code, and all the $_POST variables were empty.

In summary:

- Up to 100K -> uploads OK, I see the "Yes" on the output
- Somewhere between 100K and ~300K -> I am able to execute the PHP code but all   $_POST variables are empty
- Above ~300K -> Timeouts

This is the code:

```
<?php

   if( $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST" )
   {
      if( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["error"] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK )
      {
         echo "Yes";
      }
   }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="TestFileUpload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

This is the relevant httpd.conf

```
LimitRequestBody 20000000
```

This is the relevant php.ini

```
max_execution_time = 1800
max_input_time = -1
post_max_size = 100M
upload_max_filesize = 100M
memory_limit = 1024M
```

This is Apache's access.log

```
127.0.0.1 - - [14/Jan/2016:11:01:39 -0200] "GET /TestFileUpload.php HTTP/1.1" 200 280
127.0.0.1 - - [14/Jan/2016:11:02:10 -0200] "POST /TestFileUpload.php HTTP/1.1" 408 221
```

This is Apache's error.log (I cleared it and restarted the server to have a clean output)

```
[Thu Jan 14 10:57:00.709518 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 4972:tid 448] AH01873: Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
[Thu Jan 14 10:57:00.738518 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4972:tid 448] AH00455: Apache/2.4.6 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1e PHP/5.5.5 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Jan 14 10:57:00.739518 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4972:tid 448] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC11 Server built: Jul 15 2013 20:13:45
[Thu Jan 14 10:57:00.739518 2016] [core:notice] [pid 4972:tid 448] AH00094: Command line: 'C:\\Program Files\\Apache Software Foundation\\Apache24\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache24'
[Thu Jan 14 10:57:00.753518 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4972:tid 448] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 1952
[Thu Jan 14 10:57:02.548518 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 1952:tid 396] AH01873: Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
[Thu Jan 14 10:57:02.575518 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1952:tid 396] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.
```

I'm NOT using mod_security in Apache.

Any ideas what else I can try, any configurations?

Comment: Try: http://resumablejs.com/

Comment: Paste php.ini and httpd.conf (best via pastie or sth like this.)

Comment: mod_fcgid or php5_apache2 mod? Look at FcgidMaxRequestLen, FcgidBusyTimeout, http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#timeout

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into timeout settings in the fcgid sections of your httpd configuration files?

```
<IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
[settings]
</IfModule>
```

It may be the FcgidBusyTimeout setting. The default value is 100; and increasing this may help you out. Try:

```
<IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
FcgidBusyTimeout 9999
</IfModule>
```